# getAttribute is not setting

Tags: javascript, html

I need these two drop-down boxes to be synced based on selection of the first box.

I cannot use the `"value"` tag for this as the codebase pulls in these values from elsewhere.

The following code does not work:

**html**

```
<select name="alpha">
  <option id="1" data-sync="1">One</option>
  <option id="2" data-sync="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option id="3" data-sync="3">Three</option>
  <option id="4" data-sync="1">Four One</option>
  <option id="5" data-sync="2">Five Two</option>
</select>
<select name="beta">
  <option value="1" id="1" name="1" syncOne="1">2</option>
  <option value="2" name="2"  id="2" syncOne="2">4</option>
  <option value="3" name="3" id="3" syncOne="3">6</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementsByName("alpha")[0].onchange = function()
    {
        document.getElementsByName("beta")[0].getAttribute("syncOne") = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-sync"); 
    }

    // Trigger when loading.
    document.getElementsByName("alpha")[0].onchange();
}
```

However, the next code change works but is out of project spec (I can't use `value` attribute).

```
document.getElementsByName("beta")[0].value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-sync");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: syncOne is not an attribute of beta, it's the attribute of beta's option so following code should not work document.getElementsByName("beta")[0].getAttribute("syncOne")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that `syncOne` isn't an attribute of `<select name="beta">`, instead it is an attribute available on each option related to that selector, so next code will not result on what you are expecting:

```
document.getElementsByName("beta")[0].getAttribute("syncOne") = ...;
```

Now, one solution is to use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the related `option` element from the `beta` selector, and then set the `selected` attribute of that option:

## Example:

```js
window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementsByName("alpha")[0].onchange = function()
  {
    let sel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-sync");
    let betaOpt = document.querySelector(`select[name="beta"] option[syncOne="${sel}"]`);
    betaOpt.selected = true;
  }

  // Trigger when loading.
  document.getElementsByName("alpha")[0].onchange();
}
```

```html
<select name="alpha">
  <option id="1" data-sync="1">One</option>
  <option id="2" data-sync="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option id="3" data-sync="3">Three</option>
  <option id="4" data-sync="1">Four One</option>
  <option id="5" data-sync="2">Five Two</option>
</select>
<select name="beta">
  <option value="1" id="1" name="1" syncOne="1">2</option>
  <option value="2" name="2" id="2" syncOne="2">4</option>
  <option value="3" name="3" id="3" syncOne="3">6</option>
</select>
```

Note, I used a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`ES6` feature) to generate the query string of `querySelector()`. In case you can't use it, you can go with string concatenation, like this:

```
let betaOpt = document.querySelector('select[name="beta"] option[syncOne="' + sel + '"]');
```

Comment: @user11490402 I'm glad to know this helps you. If you like, you can accept the answer too.